# Converting Matlab datenum to EPOCH in python

Tags: python, matlab, epoch

I have trouble converting different date-formats. One is J2000 EPOCH and the other is matlab datenum. They are created from the same data but i need to read them in python and they differ by a small margin. They differ not consequently, but in different ways from file to file which is why I need help.

The first EPOCH is: EPOCH = 638971123.070749824 (in seconds)
The first Datenum (created from the same file) is: datenum = 737881.99830887

Do anyone know how to convert one to the other without losing any information (on a ns scale)?

All methods have come close but always differed on smal ns scale. Somewhere information is lost and i dont understand where

Comment: I have tried this code:

EPOCH = 638971123070749824 *1e-9
matlab_datenum = 737881.99830887

python_datetime = datetime.datetime.fromordinal(int(matlab_datenum)) + datetime.timedelta(days=matlab_datenum%1) - datetime.timedelta(days = 366)

datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1, 12, 0) + datetime.timedelta(seconds=559889620.293)

EPOCH_TIME = datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1, 12, 0) + datetime.timedelta(seconds=EPOCH)

resulting in:
2020-03-31 23:57:33.886369
2020-03-31 23:58:43.070750

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps you:

```
python_datetime = datetime.fromordinal(int(matlab_datenum)) + timedelta(days=matlab_datenum%1) - timedelta(days = 366)
```

References [here](http://sociograph.blogspot.com/2011/04/how-to-avoid-gotcha-when-converting.html).

Comment: I Have tried:

EPOCH = 638971123070749824 *1e-9 #Given in nanoseconds (J2000 format)
matlab_datenum = 737881.99830887

python_datetime = datetime.datetime.fromordinal(int(matlab_datenum)) + datetime.timedelta(days=matlab_datenum%1) - datetime.timedelta(days = 366)

EPOCH_TIME = datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1, 12, 0) + datetime.timedelta(seconds=EPOCH)

results:
2020-03-31 23:57:33.886369
2020-03-31 23:58:43.070750